# Problems in implement reCaptcha V3 in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am using Google reCaptcha v3. I am trying to implement it onto my profile page.It's load and shown in my page ,but when I want to verify it ,it does not work ,I am using this package:https://github.com/RyanDaDeng/laravel-google-recaptcha-v3#settings

in this config :

```
    'secret_key' => env('RECAPTCHA_V3_SECRET_KEY', '6LcqC'),
    'site_key' => env('RECAPTCHA_V3_SITE_KEY', '6LcqnrO-K-xb'),
```

in this blade :

```
<form>
  {!!  GoogleReCaptchaV3::renderOne('contact_us_id','contact_us') !!}
</form>
```

in my controller:

```
    public function get_data_edit(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate(
        [
            'phone' => ['required', 'max:11', new phone],
            'year' => 'nullable|numeric',
            'month' => 'nullable|numeric|max:12',
            'day' => 'nullable|numeric|max:31',
            'sex' => 'nullable|boolean',
            'marital_status' => 'nullable|boolean',
            'f_name' => 'required|max:15',
            'l_name' => 'required|max:20',
            'job' => 'nullable|string',
            'email' => 'nullable|email',
            'national_code' => 'nullable|min:10|max:10',
            'family_role' => 'nullable|string',
            'g-recaptcha-response' => [new GoogleReCaptchaV3ValidationRule('contact_us')]
        ],
        []

    );
```

where is my problem ?

Comment: as per the github repo you added it shows that the script is rendered outside of form (see [here](https://github.com/RyanDaDeng/laravel-google-recaptcha-v3#form--action))& it seems logical, but you are using renderOne() inside the form tags.

Comment: @bhucho  I am using render too ,but it does not work!!!

Comment: I am saying move render & renderone outside form tags `<form>`

Comment: @bhucho I am put out of the tag form too ,it does not show any error but Changes do not apply